# Connect-SPOService stopped working yesterday after 7pm

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

We have a PowerShell script that runs every hour to generate a list of SharePoint sites into a CSV file. It connects to SharePoint via these commands:

```
$Username = "username@ourdomain.com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "dumdeedum" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $Password
Connect-SPOService -Url https://ourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $Credential
```

Sometime after 7pm last night, it stopped working and generates this error:

> Connect-SPOService : The sign-in name or password does not match one
>   in the Microsoft account system. At C:\Users\username\OneDrive -
>   Tenant\My Scripts\Test-SharePointConnection.ps1:4 char:1
>   + Connect-SPOService -Url https://ourtenant-admin.sharepoint.c ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-SPOService], IdcrlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.Connec
>   tSPOService

I don't know whether there is a fault with our SharePoint tenant or something has changed re-authentication. My suspicion is multi-factor authentication which is turned on for the account we are using but we turned that on months ago so perplexed why it might have just caused a problem.

Comment: Just thought of app passwords and that appears to have worked... still perplexed why it stopped working yesterday when MFA has been on for months

Comment: Microsoft is having an MFA outage at the moment.

Comment: Ahh that could be related!